# How Can I Remove Non-Breaking Leading Whitespace in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, non-breaking-characters

Say I have a string variable, `" Fruit"`.

Usually, I use `strtrim()` to remove the leading whitespace. Therefore, `" Fruit"` becomes `"Fruit"`.

However, if the leading whitespace is non-breaking, i.e. `char(160)`, then strtrim, as well as its cousins - `deblank` and `strtok` - cannot remove this leading whitespace.

I also tried to use a for loop to replace `" Fruit"` with `"Fruit"` but the for loop doesn't seem to recognize `" Fruit"`, which indicates I'm identifying it incorrectly.

Here is my for loop

```
for i=1:height(T)
    if T.Foods(i) == " Fruit"
        T.Foods(i) = "Fruit"
    end
end
```

What is one way I can remove this leading, non-breaking whitespace, or at least, replace it with a variable without whitespaces?

Comment: To compare strings use Matlab's `strcmp` function instead of `someString == otherString`. But it is better to use Wolfie's answer below.

Comment: @JAC for `'character arrays'` it's important to use `strcmp`, for `"strings"` using `==` is fine, although that is a tangent from this question

Comment: @Wolfie. You are right. I thought of `strcmp` because the question that starts "I have a string variable". and used double quotes, which Matlab takes as strings. However, at least in Matlab 2018b, the `==` does work with both strings and char arrays, and so does `strcmpi`. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexprep` to match the regular expression `\s` (any whitespace character) and replace with `''`

```
>> str = [char(160), 'fru', char(160), 'it', char(160), char(160)]
str =
    ' fru it  '

>> regexprep( str, '\s', '' )
ans =
    'fruit'
```

As noted in the comments, to target only leading whitespace you would use

```
regexprep( str, '^\s+', '' )
```

Comment: To remove only leading space you need to anchor the space as `regexprep(str, '^\s', '')` where the caret `^` means the beginning of the string. If you want to remove multiple leading blanks, use the quantifier `+` as in `regexprep(str, '^\s+', '')`. The `+` means one or more of the preceding character. Note also that `\s` applies not only to a `char(160)` but also to tabs, returns, and new lines.